# Grep doesn't seem to find all matches in a file I expect

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I'm not sure if I don't fully understand `grep` or if regexes are the source of my problem, so I have two questions.  I have a simple test file named `test.txt` with the following contents:

`$ cat test.txt 
Settings.xml
blah
Settings_1.xml
blah
Settings_2.xml`

When I run `grep` in a directory containing only the above test file with the following command, it returns with no matches:

`$ grep -ir "Settings*xml"`

**1) Why is the wildcard `*` not catching the period?**

And when I run `grep` as such:

`$ grep -ir "Settings*.xml"`

the only difference being the period after the wildcard, the results are:

`test.txt:Settings.xml`

**2) Why is `grep` not finding the other two matches?**

Comment: It looks like the `*` wasn't doing what I thought (see the answer from @ArkadiuszDrabczyk)

A solution that does return what I want is:
```$ grep -ir "Settings[[:alnum:][:punct:]]*.xml"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `*` is a special character in regular expressions and means
`zero or more preceding characters`. You have to escape `*` to mean a
literal `*` character with `\`. So in your examples:

`grep -ir "Settings*xml"`

would search for a string that starts with `Setting`, and then has
zero or more `s` characters and `xml` at the end. There is no such
string in your file because `xml` is always preceded with `.`. And this:

`grep -ir "Settings*.xml"`

would search for a string that starts with `Setting`, and then has
zero or more `s` and `.xml` after zero or more `s` letters.

Your first regex would match something like this:

`Settingssxml`

Comment: You mean `*` in your first sentences.

Answer (score 4):

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1236987/432690) explains what happened, it answers your explicit questions. My answer is intended to introduce a broader context.

I guess you expected `*` to match zero or more characters (any characters) and `.` to literally mean `.`. This works with shell globbing, i.e. if you had *files* like this:

```
$ ls -1
Settings.xml
blah
Settings_1.xml
Settings_2.xml
```

then (say, in `bash`) you could do:

```
$ echo Settings*.xml
Settings.xml Settings_1.xml Settings_2.xml
```

You didn't get what you expected because `grep` uses regex syntax where:

- `.` matches (almost) any character,
- `*` means "zero or more preceding characters",
- `\` forces the next character to be interpreted literally.

That's why **instead of `"Settings*.xml"` you should have used `"Settings.*\.xml"`**. In this case:

- `.*` does what you thought `*` would do,
- `\.` does what you thought `.` would do.